# Display ACF fields on WooCommerce single product page

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I've created a custom field using ACF and I want to show it in my WooCommerce single product page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out the hook that represents the place where the ACF field should be displayed, e.g. by using the [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guide](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) for the single product page.

**example**

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'view_acf_field_for_single_product', 10 );

function view_acf_field_for_single_product(){  
  if (function_exists('the_field')){
    the_field('field_name');
  }

}
```

This is adapted from https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-with-woocommerce/.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input
Do I need to replace "the_field" with my field name and  do I need to replace this also "view_acf_field_for_single_product" ?
I've no experience in this that's why I'm asking.

Comment: the_field() is a function provided by ACF. What you need to change is field_name because this is the field you have specified in ACF. The function name can be chosen by you as well but needs to be consistent