# Display ACF fields on WooCommerce single product page via hook

Tags: woocommerce, hook, advanced-custom-fields

This method works fine
[Display ACF fields on WooCommerce single product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852816/display-acf-fields-on-woocommerce-single-product-page)
but what if I want to use this code below. How do I have to format the code so that it works with the functions.php

```
$my_title = get_field('the_subtitle');
<?php if($my_title):?>
<span id="product-subtitle" class="product-subtitle subtitle"><?php echo $my_title;?></span>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Where do you want to show this content on your single page? there are multiple hooks to show the content on single page.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for your reply.
I have fixed it in the meantime

`add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'view_acf', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'view_acf', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'view_acf', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'view_acf', 15 );

        function view_acf() { ?>

            <?php if(get_field('untertitel')) { ?>
                <div class="product-subtitle"><?php the_field('untertitel'); ?></div>
            <?php }
            }`